# How do I put a picture so you resize?

Tags: html, css

I have this site :

http://reliance.dg-site.com/es/ ---SPANISH LANGUAGE

I have this site:

http://reliance.dg-site.com/--- ENGLISH LANGUAGE

I want the picture on the front page (website in Spanish) to be the first page of the site English.

I do not understand why not look good in Spanish website ... I want to resize my image

This is code css:

```
   .page-id-553 #content
{

background:url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg")
}
```

Image size is too large? I tried to do less but unfortunately it still does not look too good

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I can't see a difference between the spanish and english page and the image you defined as background image does not seem to be available inside the themes folder. Please extend your question so that people may help.

Comment: add

body {
background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg");
}

and remove the content inside

.page-id-553 #content{ .... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your site and found a change in the css.

In http://reliance.dg-site.com/, you have used

```
background-image: url(http://reliance.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/shutterstock_132802436-13.jpg);
```

for your body tag.

But in  http://reliance.dg-site.com/es/

```
.page-id-553 #content
{

background:url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg")
}
```

So, Remove the code inside .page-id-553 #content{ } and add

```
body {
background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg");
}
```

If you want to use a background for this page then try

```
body.page-id-553 {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg");
}
```

Comment: your code is good but I want to put body image only on the first page ... not everywhere.I tried .page-id-553 body
{

background:url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg")
}

Comment: body.page-id-553 {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/reliance/images/ccc.jpg");
}

This will work for you :)

hope I was helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, if you could be a little more specific with what you need in future that would be a massive help. Also if you show methods you have attempted also that would help narrow down the issue.

For now, based on what you said, I believe this would achieve what you are after. I simply applied these to the .page-id-553 #content class/id within the console.

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: I added your code ... almost perfect but still can not see the full picture.
I put the code with Firebug ... still not on server

Comment: I'm not sure what else you would need to add, but without image resizing that's about the best that I believe it's going to get.

Comment: I like the picture on the website in Spanish to be the same as that of the website in English .Now it clearer?

Comment: You need to add <img width="2000" height="1100" src="http://reliance.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/shutterstock_132802436-13.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="shutterstock_132802436-(1)">

To the relevant place under header.entry-header in order for it to be alike, rather than a background image that is used on the other.